# Getting "error": "No text provided" when trying to post content to V2/Profile of personality insights API

Tags: python, json, ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, personality-insights

I have deployed watson-developer-cloud/personality-insights-python module in to bluemix and created an APP in Bluemix. The link for my app is running absolutely fine. However, when I want to invoke /v2/profile api, with a post request I am getting an error. Here is the code I used in Python.

```
import requests, json

payload = {'id': 'my-id',
  'userid': 'id-here',
  'sourceid' : 'twitter',
  'contenttype' : 'text/plain',
  'language' : 'en',
  'content' : 'text to analyse goes here'
}
input_data=json.dumps(payload);
r = requests.post("http://MY-APP.mybluemix.net/v2",
  auth=("USERNAME", "PASSWORD"),
  headers = {"content-type": "application/json"},
  data=input_data)

print(r.content)
```

I keep getting this error.

`b'{"help": "http://www.ibm.com/smarterplanet/us/en/ibmwatson/developercloud/doc/personality-insights/#overviewInput", "error": "The number of words 1 is less than the minimum number of words required for analysis: 100", "code": 400}'`

If I change the url with out V2, then we are getting this error

`b'{"code": 400, "error": "No text provided"}'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that you should not be POSTing to that URL. If you develop a local application, you need to bind a Personality Insights service to a Bluemix app, and take the credentials from there (there is a URL, username and password that you can use -- the URL will start with https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/personality-insights/...). If I am wrong and this is a Bluemix app, then you should parse the VCAP_CREDENTIALS object and take the credentials from there -- see the [sample applications](http://www.ibm.com/smarterplanet/us/en/ibmwatson/developercloud/doc/personality-insights/sample.shtml) in the documentation.

Then, once you get the right URL, please pay attention to that "The number of words ...." error. This means Personality Insights just cannot analyze a piece of text so small. It needs at least 100 words from its internal dictionary to match; and much beyond that, you need to provide at least 2000 or 3000 words to get an analysis with meaningful results. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks Herchu. It worked!! admire the prompt response